# Convert text file into SpreadSheet Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to convert a brut file into .txt then into spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

I've already seen a way to convert xls into Google SpreadSheet with this script (using Drive API V2) :

```
function convert_XLS_To_SpreadSheet(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('RootFolder').next().getFoldersByName('depository').next();
  var txtFile = folder.getFilesByName('file.xls').next();
  Logger.log('Text File : ' + txtFile);

  
  var resource = {
    title : txtFile.getName(),
    mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id : folder.getId()}],
  }

  Drive.Files.insert(resource, txtFile.getBlob(),{
    convert: true
  });

  txtFile.setTrashed(true);
}
```

I tried to do the same by replacing the file I wanted into txt format but it's giving me a Google Doc even if I provide the correct MimeType.

Comment: For clarification: What is a "brut" file?

Comment: what are the delimiters?

Comment: Hi, delimiters are TAB @Cooper

Comment: Brut File -> a file without extension @andrewjames

Comment: What are the end of line delimiters?

Comment: I'm not sure about this because I'm using an extraction from SAP that I don't main but is this very important for converting ? I can show you the result from an Excel macro which working

Comment: Yeah.  The structure of the file is important to know.

Answer (score 1):

Column Delimiter: \t

Line Delimiter: \n

Code:

```
function bf2ss() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('fileId');
  let lA = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\n/);
  let fA = lA.map(r => r.split(/\t/));
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,fA.length,fA[0].length).setValues(fA);
}
```

Sheet1:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great;  I didn't understood about 'end of line delimiters' thought it was a specific char but now it's ok !